# combine one element with all other elements of a different column

Tags: r, loops, combinations, tournament

I do have two pairs of players in each group (a1 - a8) and I want to combine the elements of one matchup with the second matchup to get every combination for each person with the other matchup.

```
#groups a1-a8 with two matchups

$a1
     [,1]     [,2]    
[1,] "Paul"   "Stefan"
[2,] "Markus" "Andre" 

$a2
     [,1]     [,2]   
[1,] "Julian" "Lupo" 
[2,] "Jo"     "Peter"
...
```

so I need something like this..

```
matchups for a1
   
$Paul
              [,1]     [,2]    
        [1,] "Paul"   "Paul"
        [2,] "Stefan" "Andre" 

$Markus
             [,1]     [,2]    
        [1,] "Markus" "Markus"
        [2,] "Stefan" "Andre" 
       
$Stefan  
             [,1]     [,2]    
        [1,] "Stefan" "Stefan"
        [2,] "Paul"   "Markus" 
   
$Andre
             [,1]     [,2]    
        [1,] "Andre"  "Andre"
        [2,] "Paul"   "Markus"
```

the same should be possible for each group (a2 -> a8)

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: This does not completely solve your problem, but it might be useful 
`library(data.table);
dt <- data.table(v1=c("Paul","Markus"),
                 v2=c("Stefan","Andre"));

tmp1 <- CJ(player1=dt$v1,player2=dt$v2);
tmp2 <- CJ(player1=dt$v2,player2=dt$v1);
tmp <- rbind(tmp1,tmp2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick (just replace a1 in all places if you want other matchups):
`split(expand.grid(a=a1[,1], b=a1[,2]), a1[,1])`

Comment: thanks for that! used your way to solve my problem! Added a little bit of code to solve a order problem which arose. But it basically worked.
  table <- expand.grid(a=data[,1], b=data[,2])
  sort <- factor(data[,1], levels = unique(data[,1]))
  a <- split(table,sort)